# Java 8 filtering to order data based on type within a list?

Tags: java-8

I have an array list of type `PARENT` and subtypes in the list, let's call them `CHILD1` and `CHILD2`.

Currently, my list looks like `[CHILD1 x, CHILD2 y, CHILD1, a]` but I *want* to have the `CHILD1` elements come first, IE 
`[CHILD1 x, CHILD1 a, CHILD2, y]`

Is there a grouping by type filter I can apply within a stream?

Comment: All you have to do is to write a rather simple `Comparator` implementation using `instanceof` or `getClass().getName()` and pass it down to `sorted()` stream method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the number of subtypes is not too large and that you are not dealing with further subtypes of the children, you can simply make a list of subtypes with the order you want and sort by the position in the list:

```
List<Class<? extends Parent>> order = Arrays.asList(Child1.class, Child2.class, Child3.class, ...);
Comparator<Parent> bySubtype = Comparator.comparing(p -> order.indexOf(p.getClass()));

list.sort(bySubtype);  // sort in place

List<Parent> sorted = list.stream()
                         .sorted(bySubtype)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());   // sort into a new list with a stream
```

Comment: This seems to be outputting exactly what I put into it

Comment: How can I use instanceof for this to get the actual type?

Comment: I typed it up in ideone and it works correctly:  https://www.ideone.com/XDn9PS.  If your code isn't working, please include it in your question.

Comment: I fixed it by doing the comparator using instance of and returning -1 or +1 based on the instance type. Thanks for your initial code